# What explanations are there for God's lack of culpability for the sin that was a part of the plan of salvation?

Tags: soteriology, sin

Acts 2:22-24 NET says:

> 22 “Men of Israel, listen to these words: Jesus the Nazarene, a man
> clearly attested to you by God with powerful deeds, wonders, and
> miraculous signs that God performed among you through him, just as you
> yourselves know— 23 this man, who was handed over by the predetermined
> plan and foreknowledge of God, you executed by nailing him to a cross
> at the hands of Gentiles. 24 But God raised him up, having released
> him from the pains of death because it was not possible for him to be
> held in its power.

1 Peter 1:18-20 NET says

> 18 You know that from your empty way of life inherited from your
> ancestors you were ransomed—not by perishable things like silver or
> gold, 19 but by precious blood like that of an unblemished and
> spotless lamb, namely Christ. 20 He was foreknown before the
> foundation of the world but was manifested in these last times for
> your sake. 21 Through him you now trust in God, who raised him from
> the dead and gave him glory, so that your faith and hope are in God.

These passages and others clearly indicate that salvation through the crucifixion, death, and resurrection of Jesus was the plan from the beginning.

I'm concerned specifically with the plan of salvation since it is defined explicitly as a detailed plan from the beginning.

That means that the sin of those involved in enabling the crucifixion was a part of the plan from the beginning: Judas's betrayal, the condemnation by the Jewish elite, etc.

Succinctly, this means that, from the beginning, sin was a part of the plan to save us from sin.

What explanations are there for this that address the logical conclusion that God is the author of the sins included as part of his plan for salvation, via the crucifixion of Christ, from the beginning?

Comment: Not having the time to post a thorough answer, allow me to suggest that it wasn't so much sin that was part of the plan, but choice. Suggesting that knowing some would choose to sin and therefore planing for it makes God culpable is a bit like being culpable for the burglarization of your own house because, knowing some would choose to sin, you installed an alarm.

Comment: Despite the wisdom of God knowing the inevitable liability of creating sentient beings, yet Deity, unanimously, purposed to overcome that liability in Divine righteousness, in order that God should 'bring many sons to glory'. Such is the love of God that he spared not his own Son but delivered him up for all. And who shall find fault with such Divine goodness ?

Comment: @JBH I appreciate your answer. As discussed in the comments on Mike's answer, I think the source of my confusion, in terms of your analogy, is that I can't differentiate an omni being with infallible plans installing an alarm because he knew a burglary would happen, or planning a burglary of his own home and installing an alarm because he knew it was his plan. My presuppositions were based exclusively on the latter, but now I don't see how to divorce the two situations, or how they coexist, but that's a different question entirely

Comment: @NigelJ My issue is that all do not come to the Son, and if that fact was something God proactively planned, not just knew about, then how can they said to be responsible for themselves when they were incapable of deviating from God's plan for them? As I said to you earlier, this means that submitting to God's will for some, means proceeding to eternal damnation, accepting their inevitable fate.

Comment: @cma00014 your questions are good and think you may find so encouraging answers  in a book called " The problem of Evil and Judgments of God" by A.E. Knoch.  Available on Amazon.

Comment: I always encourage people to study the scriptures that are given in this book, along with the interlinear definitions of the Greek words.  God truly does work all things out with the council of His will, superseding man's will. After all God has a choice as well, and had a definite purpose for everything, Including evil that is over come with good.  His love never fails, even though it may take a couple ages to bring forth His perfect creation reconciled back to Him.   I know this  question had been closed so thought this book may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your problem lies in God's perfect foreknowledge:

> Remember the former things of old: for I am God, and there is none else; I am God, and there is none like me, Declaring the end from the beginning, and from ancient times the things that are not yet done, saying, My counsel shall stand, and I will do all my pleasure: - Isaiah 46:9-10

The entrance of a [sinful disposition into the fabric of humanity](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%203&version=KJV) is clearly presented in the Bible as the result of human choice and, contrary to some philosophies, the Bible does not present perfect foreknowledge as ruling out the actuality of human choice.  [Nor is it required philosophically](https://iep.utm.edu/foreknow/).

Holding on to the understanding that God foreknew what choice Adam (the first man) would make and how that choice would affect and influence every person following and coupling it with the Scriptures which indicate that, in God's economy, the Lamb of God (Jesus) was crucified from the very beginning:

> Forasmuch as ye know that ye were not redeemed with corruptible things, as silver and gold, from your vain conversation received by tradition from your fathers; But with the precious blood of Christ, as of a lamb without blemish and without spot: Who verily was foreordained before the foundation of the world, but was manifest in these last times for you - 1 Peter 1:18-20

> And all that dwell upon the earth shall worship him, whose names are not written in the book of life of the Lamb slain from the foundation of the world. - Revelation 13:8

leaves a picture of God, foreknowing everything, first offering up His Son and then creating.  As surely as God foreknew Adam would sin even before He created anything (rendering it an actuality in God's economy) so was the Lamb of God crucified prior to the creation of Adam (again in God's economy) and prior to sin's actuality in time.

This magnifies God's justice and mercy in providing the rescue prior to the necessity and magnifies His great love in that the immense personal cost to redeem us was paid up front.

Thus, if one desires any blame for the existence of evil to be attached to God it would have to be blame for creating anything at all but, C.S. Lewis has astutely said,
"It is no good talking about the benefit or detriment of non-existence.".  To do so is to surmise that God, knowing the end from the beginning and the fullness of all possible creations, has chosen to implement something that is less than the best.  Of course we, as mere parts of creation, have no ground to stand upon in making such judgements:

> “The greatest barrier I have met is the almost total absence from the minds of my audience of any sense of sin... The early Christian preachers could assume in their hearers, whether Jews, Metuentes, or Pagans, a sense of guilt. (That this was common among Pagans is shown by the fact that both Epicureanism and the mystery religions both claimed, though in different ways, to assuage it.) Thus the Christian message was in those days unmistakably the Evangelium, the Good News. It promised healing to those who knew they were sick. We have to convince our hearers of the unwelcome diagnosis before we can expect them to welcome the news of the remedy.  The ancient man approached God (or even the gods) as the accused person approaches his judge. For the modern man, the roles are quite reversed. He is the judge: God is in the dock. He is quite a kindly judge; if God should have a reasonable defense for being the god who permits war, poverty, and disease, he is ready to listen to it. The trial may even end in God’s acquittal. But the important thing is that man is on the bench and God is in the dock.” - C.S. Lewis "God in the Dock:Essays on Theology and Ethics"

We can accept Divine revelation or revile it ... human choice once again (and it's attendant consequence) but with what folly does the finite judge the infinite and the temporal the eternal.

> Shall the thing formed say to him that formed it, Why hast thou made me thus? - Romans 9:20b

Comment: I believe my question rests on my presumption that God knew about the sin because it was a part of His PLAN. If I'm understanding your answer correctly, your proposition is that God planned for the sin because He KNEW it would occur. Basically I presumed the foreknowledge is a consequence of the plan, but you're saying that the plan is a consequence of foreknowledge? Thinking about it, I don't understand how they can be consequentially separated... either my way or your way

Comment: @cma0014 The proposition is that God, foreknowing the evil choices humans would make if He created them with choice, not only created anyhow but pre-ordained the means of their salvation.  As I said in my answer, God can not be said to have planned sin in any sense other than foreknowing it would happen and creating nonetheless.   Does that help clarify?

Comment: Yes it does to a degree. I still can't say I understand why God decided it was good to create despite knowing sin would cause the loss of some, but you've addressed the specifics of my question regarding culpability

Comment: @cma0014 Thank you.  It is an important question to consider.

Answer (score 1):

As with your [previous question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/94328/what-is-the-christian-doctrine-that-balances-gods-self-sufficiency-and-perfecti) this is a philosophical enquiry not an enquiry based on the need of a sinner seeking salvation from the only source of salvation - almighty God.

Your enquiry is this : that God is the author (sic) of sins.

Thus you take no culpability yourself for the sins you have committed, nor do you seek salvation from God, who is righteous.

No, you state that it is your 'logical conclusion' that he is the author and you demand that he show 'culpability' for the sins that you, yourself, out of your own volition, have done.

(Assuming, of course, that you do have sins to confess.)

This kind of enquiry is answered within scripture.

Firstly, it is answered in the most ancient book of the bible, arguably the first scripture ever to be written down, namely the book of Job.

And God answers :

> Shall he that contendeth with the almighty, instruct him ? Job 40:2.

> Wilt thou condemn me, that thou mayest be righteous ? Job 40:8.

Secondly, such enquiries are answered by the treatise of the apostle Paul, commonly called 'Romans' in which Paul spends two chapters disposing of such enquiries.

> We are sure, he says, Romans 2:2 that the judgment of God is *according to truth*.

And later in his epistle, the apostle answers the enquiry of one who (hypothetically) queries why God finds fault with the sins of men saying,

> Nay but, O man, who art thou that repliest against God ? Shall the thing formed say to him that formed it "Why hast thou made me thus", Romans 9:20.

Thus are the answers to your enquiry.

Comment: How can it be of Judas's own volition if it was the plan from the beginning? How can repentance be sought for things that were planned from the beginning? I'm intimately familiar with your references, they are a key factor in my question. It seems to indicate that God does what he does and we're just subject to it, including the guilt for things that were planned for us to do. Am I misunderstanding any part of your answer? Also where would be a more appropriate place to get answers for questions like these?

Comment: Yes, indeed. God is righteous. (Deity is righteous, by being Deity.) And we, the created, are subject to the Creator. Anything other than that . . . . .  would be unrighteous. No, you have misunderstood nothing. Now, you simply need to be _subject_ to the reality of what is stated in scripture. Fighting against this reality will not be beneficial to yourself.

Comment: According to your answer, I'm subject to the reality no matter, including my sins that are part of the plan from the beginning, just as Judas was. Based on this answer, submission to God's sovereign will could entail repentance and salvation for some, or wrath and destruction for others. If one earnestly seeks repentance, a relationship with Christ, and freedom from sin while struggling intellectually with questions like this, can they be saved? How does one will themselves out of unbelief anymore than they can will themselves to fall in love?

Comment: _. . . . . So then it is not of him that willeth, nor of him that runneth, but of God that sheweth mercy._ Romans 9:16. Salvation is of the Lord, Jonah 2:9.

Comment: I think we should also be careful of conflating deity intrinsically with righteousness. See the Evil God Hypothesis. An all evil, omnipotent, omniscient diety is logically possible. There's also the danger that we as humans fall prey to the perception that because "might makes right" for God (He is good because He is sovereign and says He's good) it applies to our own sovereignty over others

Comment: You posit a concept called 'evil god'. I know nothing of such a person or such a concept. This is wholly down to your own unbelief. If you are referring to the Devil (Serpent, Diabolos, Tempter, Satan, Apollyon, Abaddon, Poneros, Adikios and Drakon) then best to say so. But please do not refer to the Most High God as 'evil'. Thank you.

Comment: https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/religious-studies/article/abs/evilgod-challenge/E925DF20AF17F3C87B9449B25F649F27

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142890/discussion-between-cma0014-and-nigel-j).

Comment: I shall not be joining in chat. I think we have covered everything necessary.

Comment: I disagree because my question is concerning the contradiction of culpability between "of ones own volition" and "planned from the beginning". This remains unanswered

Comment: I missed your edit to the one above. I was not referring to the God of the Bible as evil. I was merely referring to the logical construct of an evil god and the philosophical consequences that could logically be expected. My question is concerned with understanding the harmonization of God's goodness and omni traits. Something that has been thought about and discussed in the church for millennia, but I had a specific question related to it

Answer (score 0):

The verses you cite do not require God to be responsible for the evil.  Merely to *know* of it.

In the *Catholic Cathecism*

> (311) Angels and men, as intelligent and free creatures, have to journey toward their ultimate destinies by their free choice and preferential love. They can therefore go astray. Indeed, they have sinned. Thus has moral evil, incommensurably more harmful than physical evil, entered the world. God is in no way, directly or indirectly, the cause of moral evil. He permits it, however, because he respects the freedom of his creatures and, mysteriously, knows how to derive good from it:

> For almighty God. . ., because he is supremely good, would never allow any evil whatsoever to exist in his works if he were not so all-powerful and good as to cause good to emerge from evil itself.

> 312 In time we can discover that God in his almighty providence can bring a good from the consequences of an evil, even a moral evil, caused by his creatures: "It was not you", said Joseph to his brothers, "who sent me here, but God. . . You meant evil against me; but God meant it for good, to bring it about that many people should be kept alive." From the greatest moral evil ever committed - the rejection and murder of God's only Son, caused by the sins of all men - God, by his grace that "abounded all the more", brought the greatest of goods: the glorification of Christ and our redemption. But for all that, evil never becomes a good.

Comment: They require sin to take place in God's plan that was ordained from the beginning. God cannot just know of His plan for salvation, He must carry it out. In order to carry out His plan at He intended, sinful actions must have taken place. If you plan for something, and your plan is guaranteed to happen as you intend it, then everything that takes place as a part of it is a direct consequence of your intention

Answer (score -2):

These passages and others DO clearly indicate that salvation through the crucifixion, death, and resurrection of Jesus was the plan from the beginning.

The plan God is executing is based on choice. He began with two new humans and the serpent/evil force/influence. God is responsible for the sin that has cursed man for a time and he has provided a perfect and wise solution.

God could have disallowed this influence but he did not. The whole deal is to be able to compare one way of life with a totally different way of living. So in the end, when everyone will be able to choose 'life or death' as the Israelites were offered, they will know what the way of sin and evil leads to.

> “See, I have set before you today life and good, death and evil. Deut 30:15

> v19 Therefore choose life, that you and your offspring may live

We have to understand one important reality. One cannot possible choose life while they remain under the influence/grip of evil. Jesus said that the Jews were children of the Devil because they did what he did. John 8:44

God is the one who opens the heart and mind to see a new reality that he is the true God and not any other god.

God will provide ample opportunity for every person alive or dead to know the truth and to compare with what they knew. That is why the devil will be silenced during the time after the 1st resurrection and then loosed again so the newly raised dead (who knew not the truth about God or his messiah) might be offered their choice (not a second choice). If they *still* want to choose evil, they will suffer the second death and that will be the end of them.

God in his wisdom has planned that we can only be trusted to enter the kingdom for eternity with eternal life as Jesus now has, is if we have made a proper and firm choice between good and evil. That is why there will be no more sin in the new age to come.

> No one born of God makes a practice of sinning, for God’s seed abides in him; and he cannot keep on sinning, because he has been born of God. 1 john 3:9

(unfortunately the matter of being 'born from above' has been confused but that is another Q/A entirely)